# lsof doesnt seem to be showing all connections

Tags: networking, macos

I am on the latest MacOS

`nettop` shows connections from browsers and other processes.

However `lsof -n -itcp` doesnt show any connections. Is there a way to debug this?

Comment: does macos have the concept of `sudo` or a root account? that's what you should be using to run the command

Comment: When I try this on my laptop I get output from `lsof` whether or not I invoke it under `sudo`.  My individual account has Admin privileges in MacOS (Monterey), but I don't know if this makes a difference.

Comment: @SottoVoce I was able to get all connections using `lsof` on Monterey. The update to Ventura broke something... Have you checked on Ventura?